# Moving all files except specific file to folder vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to move all my files to another folder using vbscript but somehow I can't seem to get it right. I've executed my code but the filename that I don't want also moves to the folder that I've created. Can you help me with this?

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Users\Desktop\Other Files\Excel 
Files")

If objFolder.Name <> "TestResults.xlsx" Then

objFSO.Movefile "C:\Users\Users\Desktop\Other Files\Excel Files\*", 
"C:\Users\Users\Desktop\Sample Folder"

End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I've executed my code but the filename that I don't want also moves to the folder that I've created.*

Its because you are moving all the files because you used *

There are few issues with your code like `If objFolder.Name <> "TestResults.xlsx"` even though your object refers to folders only.

Then you moved all the files - you gotta traverse the folder and filter out the files which are not to be moved

Try below code

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Users\Desktop\Other Files\Excel Files").Files

For Each objFile In objFolder
    If objFile.Name <> "TestResults.xlsx" Then
        objFSO.MoveFile objFile.Path, "C:\Users\Users\Desktop\Sample Folder\"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I was having a hard time in figuring out this issue... I did a couple of  research in the internet and nothing seems to work...  Thanks a lot :)